# Create Folder -> Files -> and dump data in those files

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, cmd, filesystems

I have a table with 3 columns: Folder Directory, File Name and Data. I want to create folders in my file system based on the various values in column 1, then create files under that folder with name as in column 2, and finally dump all the data inside that file as in column 3. I can create an excel to have my tables's information but not sure how can I create Folders/Files and dump data recursively. Any help is highly appreciated.
[image: Table Content]

Comment: save your table as `csv`. Then `for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=," %%a in (table.csv) do (md "%%a" & (echo/%%c)>"%%a\%%b"`

Comment: SSIS would be able to do this, or you could use PowerShell. T-SQL is probably not the best tool to achieve this. You've tagged PowerShell so could you show us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how it could look in Powershell:

Input.csv looks like this:

```
Folder Directory,FILE NAME,DATA
Main/A,FILE-A1,DATA-A1
Main/A,FILE-A2,DATA-A2
Main/B,FILE-B1,DATA-B1
Main/C,FILE-C1,DATA-C1
```

And the script looks like this:

```
# Load CSV into variable
$CSV = Import-Csv 'C:\script\test\input.csv'

# Set root folder for new folders to be created in
$FolderRoot = 'C:\script\test\root'

# Iterate through each line in $CSV
foreach ($Line in $CSV) {
    # Join $FolderRoot and the folder from the current line to a proper path
    $Path = (Join-Path $FolderRoot $Line.'Folder Directory')
    # Check if folder already exists, create it if not.
    if (!(Test-Path $Path)) {
        New-Item -Path $Path -ItemType Directory
    }
    # Write the content of the DATA column into the file in the FILE NAME column.
    # Change to Add-Content if you want to add info to the file instead of overwriting.
    Set-Content -Path (Join-Path $Path $Line.'FILE NAME') -Value $Line.'DATA'
}
```

Join-Path is nice because it automatically handles backslashes, forward slashes, trailing slashes etc and creates a proper path.

Comment: Dear PMental, this worked for me like magic :). I had not much idea about Powershell script but yes you made so easy to understand. I have no words to thank you. Keep it up.